# Apply action to a span not a link?

Tags: jquery

With the help from some great people on here i'va manged to get a jQuery hover tooltip working :).. Next step is actually applying the hover to a span class rather than a link... (As I don't need them to link...but in the future I may need to add a clickable link) so currently...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tippytrip').hover(function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    console.log(offset)
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
        var tooltipId = this.hash;
        $('#tooltip-container').empty().load
('tooltips.html ' + tooltipId).show();
        $('#tooltip-container').css({top:offset.top, 
left:offset.left + width + 10}).show();
    }, function(){
        $('#tooltip-container').hide();
});
    });
```

The part I think is the culprit is:

```
var tooltipId = this.hash;
```

I've tried all sorts of things, basically I need to change it from:

```
<a href="#tip1" class="tippytrip">Show Tip 1 - again</a>
```

to:

```
<span class="tippytrip" rel="tip1">Show Tip 1</span>
```

Many thanks

Comment: I think a link would be actually be fine, but you simply have to change it to `var tooltipId = '#' + $(this).attr('rel');`, although `rel` is not a valid attribute for `span` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tooltipId = $(this).attr("rel");
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks, i'll accept in 7 minutes, when stackoverflow lets me! lol

Answer (score 1):

Change it to read:

```
var tooltipId = $(this).attr('rel');
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `rel`,I would use the `data` attribute i.e.

`<span class="tippytrip" data-tooltip="tip1">Show Tip 1</span>`

and then, as atornblad suggests, change the `var tooltipId` line to

`var tooltipId = $(this).data("tooltip");`